# How to ring multiple workers in Twilio Flex

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

In Twilio Flex, when a call comes in, I want all workers in a given queue to ring.
They should all be able to pick up the call and the first one to do so is connected to the customer while the call disappear for the others.

For now, TaskRouter seems to select a single eligible worker to send the call.

**How can I have TaskRouter to simulring all  eligible workers instead of ringing them one by one?**

Comment: Possibly reference this TR functionality - https://www.twilio.com/changelog/taskrouter-now-dials-only-one-worker-multi-reservation.

Comment: @Alan this link is not totally relevant but allowed me to find the solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alan's comment got me in the right direction.
To have multiple workers ring at the same time, just increase the MAX RESERVED WORKERS property in the TaskQueue.